# Can I add wild card to Connections(i)?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have macro which makes queries and one pivot table. I need to add wild card in

```
For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Connections.Count
Set qr = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Connection2").ODBCConnection
    qr.CommandText = iSql
```

where `("Connection2")` the number `2` is what change. I want use wild card instead of the number.

Comment: that makes no sense? you need to replace 2 with some other number is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to use a wildcard in the connection name. But even if you were able to then what purpose could it solve especially in a loop? It will always give you the same name.

Alternative?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Connections.Count
        If ThisWorkbook.Connections(i).Name Like "Connection*" Then
            Set qr = ThisWorkbook.Connections(ThisWorkbook.Connections(i).Name).ODBCConnection
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

But like I said if there were two connections say `Connection1` and `Connection2`. You will always get `Connection1` for the above.

Comment: BTW you can also use `INSTR()` if you do not want to use `LIKE`. For example `If Instr(1,ThisWorkbook.Connections(i).Name,"Connection",vbTextCompare) Then`